# Image is faded and having colored overlay while generated from PDF using PDFBox

Tags: pdfbox

I am trying to generate image from the PDF pages using org.apache.pdfbox API, Version 3.0.0-RC1.

The code works perfectly without any issue while executing in my local windows Java 8 environment, however while executed in the Linux system, there is colored overlay added on top of the images and is not generated correctly.

Image rendered from PDF page in Windows 10:

[image: Image rendered from PDF page in Windows 10]

Image rendered from PDF page in Linux 7:

[image: Image rendered from PDF page in Linux 7]

I have also tried using previous API versions 2.0.25 and 1.8.0 from the PDFbox and that is also having same issue. I also tried using another API org.swinglabs - pdf-renderer, version 1.0.5 with no luck.

I already validated java versions in my local windows 10 system and Linux 7 system. Windows 10 is "Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09)" and Linux 7 is "Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
". The issue is consistently happening in the Linux system. I have gone through various solutions from github and stackoverflow and could not get any help. My sample code while using PDFBox API, Version 3.0.0-RC1 is -

```
List<BufferedImage> extractedImages = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
byte[] fileData = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(localFile);
PDDocument pddDoc = Loader.loadPDF(fileData);
PDFRenderer pr = new PDFRenderer (pddDoc);
for (int pageNumber = 0; pageNumber < pddDoc.getNumberOfPages(); ++pageNumber) {
    extractedImages.add(pr.renderImage(pageNumber));
}
```

Comment: Can you share an example PDF and images rendered in the different environments?

Comment: The latest version is 3.0.0-alpha3 . Please edit your question to include your code, and any log output. Also is there is reason that you're using 3.0 and not 2.0.27?

Comment: @mkl I have updated my question by adding the image generated in both environments.

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr, I originally was programming with version 2.0.25 and tried with latest RC version to check if that helps resolving the problem. I have updated the comment, mentioning the versions I tried.

Comment: Your linux jdk version is old (and so is your windows version). The current one is 362, please try that one just to be sure. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-8-ug/downloads-list.html Please share the PDF too.

Comment: *"I have updated my question by adding the image generated in both environments."* - please have a closer look at your images, there is not only the coloration: wherever there is a change of color, there also is a shift left in the image itself. Such weird coloration plus shifts in the image content usually are a sign of damaged image data. Are you sure the pdf you use on the Linux system is undamaged? Another possibility would be some image content there that the older jre on your Linux system can not handle while the newer one on your windows system can handle, so try updating.

Comment: let me update the jdk and try.

Comment: The issue exist only in linux even with jdk update to build 362.

Comment: Then share the PDF, please, for a deeper investigation.

Comment: Hi @TilmanHausherr PDF is shared at - https://drive.google.com/file/d/19jdlP5IQEvwO9p2EjorqDwzufZ6td0Yl/view?usp=sharing

As there are 10 pages in the PDF, it should generate 10 images. As highlighted there is an issue only while running application in Linux.

Comment: I have an old desktop PC with Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS installed and just ran all updates. I then installed the latest java and then ran PDFDebugger (both 2.0.27 and 3.0 alpha3) with your file and it displays properly.